# Is WC_Ajax getting checkout form changes automatically? (Without manually sending ajax data via javascript)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am learning how to use ajax to add some extra fee to the cart based on user choice on the checkout page and come across the snippet on this page: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-checkout-fees-based-on-radio-button-choice-ajax/

```
// Part 1 
// Display Radio Buttons
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice' );
  
function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice() {
     
   $chosen = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value( 'radio_choice' ) : $chosen;
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? '0' : $chosen;
        
   $args = array(
   'type' => 'radio',
   'class' => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
   'options' => array(
      '0' => 'No Option',
      '10' => 'Option 1 ($10)',
      '30' => 'Option 2 ($30)',
   ),
   'default' => $chosen
   );
     
   echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
   echo '<h3>Customize Your Order!</h3>';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
   echo '</div>';
     
}
  
// Part 2 
// Add Fee and Calculate Total
   
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee', 20, 1 );
  
function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee( $cart ) {
   
   if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    
   $radio = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );
     
   if ( $radio ) {
      $cart->add_fee( 'Option Fee', $radio );
   }
   
}
  
// Part 3 
// Add Radio Choice to Session
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session' );
  
function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session( $posted_data ) {
    parse_str( $posted_data, $output );
    if ( isset( $output['radio_choice'] ) ){
        WC()->session->set( 'radio_chosen', $output['radio_choice'] );
    }
}
```

I copy the whole thing into my function.php and it works perfectly, which raised my question.
I'd expect that in order to achieve what I want to do, I will have to write some javascript to detect user choice and send/receive data to/from woocommerce. But in this snippet there is no javascript needed. I guess that is because woocommerce has already had some javascript ready and hooked it up with WC_Ajax. Upon reading the snippet, I think the magic can only happen with this hook: `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review`. However, the doc has little to none information about it.

My guess is when user makes or changes their choice on the radio input, (even though the form hasn't been submitted) it is captured by some build-in javascript written by woocommerce and the data is sent to WC_Ajax, in turn triggers this hook. If this is the case, the question is,
What kind of user actions on the checkout page will be captured and sent to WC_Ajax?
And anyone knows where the javascript is that handles sending data? I want to read it to have a deeper understanding.

Comment: The js listens for changes on fields with the `update_totals_on_change` class

Comment: Thanks! I removed the class and the cart won't update. Question is, where do people get these information? The doc says nothing about this, googling "update_totals_on_change" returns little information.

Comment: Perhaps by reading through WC source code...

Comment: You won't get usage documentation of every source code, you'll have to download the plugin and open the folder in your IDE and then search keywords and find the connection and usage.